# Visual Studio 2013 updates via Windows Update

Tags: windows-update, visual-studio

I remember that Visual Studio 2005/2008/2010 would all automatically update via Windows Update like 99% of every other Microsoft product.

Now however it seems that Visual Studio 2013 wants you to install updates **manually**. Is there some way of re-enabling automatic updates?

I've attached screenshots of the updates and also the Windows Update, because from my searching a lot of answers are something like "make sure Windows Update says it will update other products" which mine does and yet still won't update Visual Studio.

[image]

[image]

Comment: From what I've read, it sounds like they purposely designed the updates to come from the Visual Studio app itself instead of from Windows Updates.  So not sure there is a way to get them from Windows Update.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/04/06/improving-how-we-update-visual-studio.aspx
that article kind of explains what they did.

Comment: Great /s So there is no way of automatically updating VS anymore apart from manually? What about in an enterprise environment with dozens of VS installs to update?

Comment: To be it simple.  Microsoft changed their release schedule on Visual Studio.  What use to be limited to just security updates, are now more or less, secondary and ternary product release updates.  You can push these updates like you did in the past but only if you used WSUS or SSCM ( or something equileveant )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an enterprise environment you always have the options of using WSUS or SCCM. I've used WSUS to update our team's VS2012 environment in the past. We haven't migrated to VS2013, so I don't know the situation for it but because the mechanism behind it is very simple I don't doubt that it will support VS2013 updates, too.

Here are some articles for your consideration on WSUS for VS updates:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robcaron/archive/2013/04/04/how-to-install-visual-studio-2012-update-2-offline.aspx

This one mentions VS2013 updates but the script is not something official so I can't be sure: http://www.vmwareandme.com/2014/02/How-to-install-configure-wsus-windows-server-2012-R2.html#.VHRl0hE43sk

SCCM is another way of integrating a central update mechanism but its purpose is much broader and it would be an overkill to use it just for software updates.